# Collision detection method

Tags: java, performance, game, collision, cyclomatic-complexity

I think everyone has some code they are embarrassed and not proud of and today I have decided to show mine. I'm not sure how to go about making this more efficient. At the time I was just happy it did what I wanted it to do and it's the first game I ever made. So basically, this is a collision detection method for my game and it describes which objects should collide and if they do, what should happen?

Any ideas on how to improve would be much appreciated :)

```
void collisionHandling(GameObject other) {
    //the following method details the outcome whenever one class comes into contact with another
    if ((this instanceof Heart && other instanceof Ship) && this.overlap(other)) {
        //increments ship lives if heart is hit by ship unless the ship has 5 lives
        Game.ship.dead = false;
        if (Ship.lives < 5) Game.ship.incLives();
        this.hit();
    }
    if ((this instanceof ShieldSprite && other instanceof Ship) && this.overlap(other)) {
        //makes the ship invulnerable if the sprite is hit and sets a counter till it runs out
        Game.ship.dead = false;
        Ship.invul = true;
        Game.shipInvulCounter = 400;
        this.hit();
    }
    if ((this instanceof Enemy && other instanceof Bullet) && this.overlap(other)) {
        //if the enemy gets it by a bullet it gets hit
        this.hit();
    }
    if ((this instanceof Enemy && other instanceof Ship) && this.overlap(other)) {
        //if the enemy gets it by a bullet it gets hit
        this.hit();
        other.hit();
    }
    if((this instanceof Enemy && other instanceof BigBullet) && this.overlap(other)){
        //if the enemy gets it by a big bullet it dies instantly
        this.dead = true;
        other.hit();
    }
    if((this instanceof BigBullet && other instanceof Asteroid) && this.overlap(other)){
        //if a big bullet hits an asteroid they both get hit
        other.hit();
        this.hit();
    }
    if((this instanceof Bullet && other instanceof Asteroid) && this.overlap(other)){
        //if a bullet hits an asteroid they both get hit
        other.hit();
        this.hit();
    }
    if((this instanceof EnemBigBullet && other instanceof Ship) && this.overlap(other)){
        //if an enemy big bullet hits the ship it dies instantly
        other.dead = true;
        this.hit();
    }
    //the following 'if' statements are so that if those two objects meet, they will simply glide over eachother
    if (!Ship.invul) { //if the ship is invulnerable everything glides over it
        if (!((this instanceof EnemBullet && other instanceof Asteroid) || (this instanceof Asteroid && other instanceof EnemBullet))) { //enemy bullets should not kill asteroids
            if (!(this instanceof Enemy || other instanceof Enemy)) { //enemies do not come into contact with anything other than what is mentioned above
                if(!(this instanceof EnemBigBullet || other instanceof EnemBigBullet)) {//enemy big bullets do not come into contact with anything other than what is mentioned above
                    if (!((this instanceof Bullet && other instanceof Ship) || (this instanceof Ship && other instanceof Bullet))) { //stops the bullets killing the ship when they spawn
                        if (!((this instanceof BigBullet && other instanceof Ship) || (this instanceof Ship && other instanceof BigBullet))) { //likewise with big bullets
                            if (!(this instanceof ShieldSprite || other instanceof ShieldSprite)) { //nothing collides with shield sprite except ship as mentioned before
                                if (!(this instanceof Heart || other instanceof Heart)) { //likewise for heart
                                    if (this.getClass() != other.getClass() && this.overlap(other)) { //otherwise if the classes are different then they will hit
                                        this.hit();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh boy! Did you ever hear of interfaces?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I shudder at the thought

Comment: Why actually? Those classes should decide themselves what happens when colliding with other objects. Is that implementation made within the `GameObject` class?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah this method is in the GameObject class which all the game object classes inherit from as well as overlap, update, draw and hit methods. maybe i could just make GameObject an interface and then have them implement it themselves rather than an abstract class?

Comment: This method shouldn't be implemented there as mentioned, but `GameObject` should be abstract, and the collision detection should be left to the concrete implementaations. That default behavior that both objects are `hit()` could go to some base class implementation though. Lookup the _Single Responsibility Principle_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so just keep the class abstract and move the collision handling to the individual game object classes?

Comment: That would be way more flexible for further extensions and introducing new `GameObject`'s, yes. For a reasonable review, you should provide more context into your question.

Comment: I'd say try to code it without using instanceOf. Then comeback and check @πάνταῥεῖ suggestion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay thank you for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

> *I think everyone has some code they are embarrassed and not proud of and today I have decided to show mine.*

### A pattern to get out of this mess ..

That's an impressive amount of nested if-statements. As you can see, the behavior of collision handling depends both on the current instance's type and the provided instance's type. There is a pattern suited for this kind of complexity: the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

#### `GameObject`

You first declare a base method in `GameObject` that redirects the generic collision handling to a specific method based on the type of `other`.

```
void collisionHandling (GameObject other) {
    if (this.overlap(other)) {
        if ((other instanceof Ship)) {
            collisionHandling((Ship)other);
        } else if ((other instanceof Bullet)) {
            collisionHandling((Bullet)other);
        } 
        // and so on ..
    }
}
```

#### Derived Classes

Class `Heart` could then override any such method.

```
@Override
void collisionHandling (Ship ship) {
    Game.ship.dead = false;
    if (Ship.lives < 5) Game.ship.incLives();
    this.hit();
}
```

Class `ShieldSprite` would override that method with different behavior.

```
@Override
void collisionHandling (Ship ship) {
    Game.ship.dead = false;
    Ship.invul = true;
    Game.shipInvulCounter = 400;
    this.hit();
}
```

By implementing this pattern, the cyclomatic-complexity of collision handling method gets reduced drastically and all logic sits at the right place, which makes the design object-oriented.